# How to edit a fragments layout TextView in the MainActivity.java?

Tags: android, textview, fragment

i was working with a NavigationDrawer for a menu and there is a fragment for every item on the menu for example i have a home menu which have a homefragemnt.xml and a homefragment.java so in the xml file file there is a textview i wanted to change that textviews values using the MainActivity.java 
and used the following code:`TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.changetxt);t1.setText("ChangedText");`
changetxt is the id of the TextView in the homefragment.xml file
but this code give a runtime error saying `Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference.`
What is causing this problem and how do i solve it?

Comment: Can you post the entire code?

Comment: am afraid i can't, i don't have the code on me right now you can ask me if you want to know anything

Comment: you should not access Fragment's view from Activity. You should normally ask a Fragment instance to update it's view.

Comment: You can create an Interface,override the Interface in Fragment and call the interface method from Activity to update view of Fragment.

Comment: i am kind of new to android can you suggest anything on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get the reference of textview from the fragment view not activity.
The view which you inflated in the onCreateView of fragment.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View   view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.myview,container,false);

    TextView t1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.changetxt);t1.setText("ChangedText");
        return view;
    }
```

here view is the View that the fragment is initaialised with.

[this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/dynamically-add-fragments-to-an-activity-in-android/) link will help you

Comment: yes i tried that too but it doesn't  work when i run the app on the emulator it gives error

Comment: Just on the emulator?please post code  whenever you can

Comment: yes just on the emulator.i will post the code when i can thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Fragment :

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

```
TextView t1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    t1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.changetxt);
    return view;
}

public void setTextViewText(String value){
    t1.setText(value);
}
```

}

Activity :

myFragment.setTextView("ChangedText");

Hope it helps you.